# PL/SQL Looping problems

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a pl/sql script name test

and a table name testtable

```
//testtable
a#
-----------
1
2
3
4
```

Inside my test script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(a_num IN NUMBER )
        RETURN NUMBER;
IS
        check NUMBER := 0;
        match NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) into check FROM TESTTABLE WHERE a_num = a#;

        IF check > 0 THEN
             match := match + 1;
        END IF;

        IF match = 0 THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'not found' );
             RETURN(-1);
        ELSE
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'found' );
             RETURN(0);
        END IF;
END test;
/
```

for this script, when i enter following query:

```
select test(5) from testtable;
```

the result return will be 4 times :

```
not found
not found
not found
not found
```

The following query:

```
select (test2) from testtable;
```

returns:

```
found
found
found
found
```

how to make it show only 1 message?

Comment: Your function returns a number.  The "result" you're talking about appears to be the data written to the `dbms_output` buffer.  Are you actually interested in the data returned by the function?  Or the data written to the `dbms_output` buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single result, don't select from `testtable`, select from a single-row table.  Oracle provides the `dual` table for just that purpose

```
SELECT test(5)
  FROM dual
```

and

```
SELECT test(2)
  FROM dual
```

will each return a single row of results.

Of course, this assumes that your `test` function is actually valid and that it actually returns results.  The code you posted won't compile because you have a function that does not return anything.  There is no `return` clause in the specification of the function that tells the compiler what data type the function returns.  And there is nothing in the function that returns a result.  So the function cannot possibly compile.  My assumption is that your actual function does compile and that it does return something rather than just writing to `dbms_output`.

Comment: but i need to compare with my testtable data. it's also possible?

Comment: @user3664490 - I don't understand what you mean.  In the example you posted, there is no reason to select from `testtable` when you call the function, you're already querying `testtable` inside the function.  If the actual situation is that you need to query `testtable` for some other reason, you'll probably need to help us by expanding your question to show the real problem.

Comment: just ask ya. still got another way to prevent this looping problem instead of using dual? if i want to execute the function using test but no looping problem occur?

Comment: @user3664490 - If you want a single row of results, you can select from any single-row table.  Or from any table you'd like so long as you provide a predicate that returns exactly 1 row.  For example, `select test(2) from testtable where rownum <= 2` would also do what you appear to want.  It makes no sense to do that, however, since you're not using any data from `testtable` in your query. You lose out on some optimizations that the database can perform when you're selecting from `dual` though those are probably not particularly important benefits in this case.

Comment: so since i pass using all the a#>
 [link](select test(a#) from testtable) so it's impossible to return 1 row result only? although use exception? possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you are querying a table with 5 rows and you do not provide a predicate, the result set will have 5 rows.  Your projection (things in the `SELECT` list) cannot alter the number of rows that are returned.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this code:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(a_num IN NUMBER )
     RETURN NUMBER;
IS
    check NUMBER := 0;
    match NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) into check FROM TESTTABLE WHERE a# =a_num;

    IF check > 0 THEN
         match := match + 1;
    END IF;

    IF match = 0 THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'not found' );
         RETURN(-1);
    ELSE
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'found' );
         RETURN(0);
    END IF;
END test;
/
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: what is the different ? i can't see any different here.
the answer you provide is very un-useful

Comment: don't have any differences and problem still occur

Comment: Please see carefully. I have changed the position of a# and a_num.